# Laravel 5.6: Relationship with multiple tables and conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Consider I'm a hotel owner, and I have to know the bookings related to my hotel.
I need all bookings that which associated with my hotel.
Is there any eloquent functions to join? How?

How to get bookings of a hotel with owner(userid) with using eloquent relationship functions?

[image]

Comment: Is there owner(user) has many hotels OR only one hotel?? You can simply get all bookings using `Booking::all()` query!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Admin can assign multiple hotels to a user.. so user has many...

Comment: Yah.. Booking::get() returns all but i want to display to the user so only display the bookings for that hotel owner...

Comment: I'm littile confused with documentation and the relationship could you please give me the code! @mahdi

Comment: you first need to try yourself. If you get stuck in between ask it on SO and others will try to solve it.

Comment: I'm tried.. but

Comment: ohkay fine than paste your code..

Comment: it seems that whole relation tree is builded in wrong way... to be honest and that's causing the problem.

Comment: It's hard to understand your DB structure, i suggest you that insert one column named as `hotel_owner_id` in `bookings` table and then simply get it using `owner_id(user_id)`!

Answer (score 1):

**Hotel.php**

```
class Hotel extends Model

{

    public function userId(){

      return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');

  }

  public function rooms(){

      return $this->hasMany(Room::class,'hotel_id','id');

  }

}
```

**Room.php**

```
class Room extends Model

{

  public function hotelId(){

    return $this->belongsTo(Hotel::class,'hotel_id');

  }

  public function bookings(){

      return $this->hasMany(Booking::class,'room_id','id');

  }

}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model

{

  public function hotels(){

        return $this->hasMany(Hotel::class,'user_id','id');

    }

}
```

**Below code add in your respective controller.**

```
$user = \App\User::find(Auth::id());

$hotels = $user->hotels;



foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {

  $rooms = $hotel->rooms;

  foreach ($rooms as $room) {

    print_r($room->bookings);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the relationship with user in model

```
class Booking extends Model{

  /**
 * Get the user that owns the booking.
 */
  public function owner()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class,'user_id,'id');
  }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
$bookings = Booking::with('owner')->all(); // or get() or whatever to get
```

the booking list

```
foreach($bookings as $booking){
  echo $booking->user->name; // you have access to owner fields
}
```

Comment: There is multiple Hotel owners.

Comment: @VishnuKumarPv: Now you came with new statement. You told first that owner has many hotels and now you added that hotels has many owner also!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found this.
Booking model

```
public function room( )
 {  return $this->belongsTo('App\room');
 }
public function hotel( )
{

    return $this->room()->with(['hotel'=> function($query){
        $query->with('user');
    }]);
}
```

BookingController

```
public function owner(Booking $booking )  { 
 return $booking->with('hotel')->get()
```

Next thing is Filter with owner